# How to avoid validation of nested components in vee-validate 4?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate

I use vue 3 and vee-validate 4.9.

I have the following component structure:

`Form.vue` that has `SearchUsers.vue` that has `VInput.vue`.

SearchUsers and VInput use `useField` composable.

Sometimes I need to validate VInput, but in this case, I don't. The reason is that SearchUsers uses VInput as a supplementary component, to be exact: as a search. The thing is that it is required that at least one user should be added, and this is the responsibility of SearchUsers.

If no users are selected, then the validation should not pass. And it works.

But **at the same time** VInput is being validated. That is what I don't want to do. It turns out it has a green border like it's valid, while SearchUsers display a validation error.

The components are pretty lengthy, but as I understand the problem is that when you validate a form, every input (including nested components, deeply in the component tree) is being validated. How can I configure that behavior and disable validation?

Here is an example of VInput (the same mechanism is used in SearchUsers):

```
<template>
  <div class="mb-4">
    <label
      v-if="label"
      :for="inputId"
      class="block text-sm text-slate-600 font-medium mb-1"
    >{{ label }}</label>

    <input
      :id="inputId"
      :value="value"
      :type="type"
      name="email"
      class="input"
      :class="classes"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      @input="handleChange"
      @blur="handleBlur"
    >
    <div
      v-if="description"
      class="text-sm text-slate-500 mt-1"
    >
      {{ description }}
    </div>
    <VErrorMessage v-show="errorMessage">
      {{ errorMessage }}
    </VErrorMessage>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, toRef, computed, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
import { useField } from 'vee-validate'

interface Props {
  type?: string,
  name?: string,
  modelValue: string,
  label?: string,
  placeholder?: string
  description?: string
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  type: 'text',
  modelValue: '',
  label: '',
  name: '',
  placeholder: '',
  description: ''
})

const inputId = ref<string>('')

const instance = getCurrentInstance()
if (instance) {
  inputId.value = `label-${instance.uid}`
}

const {
  value,
  errorMessage,
  meta,
  handleBlur,
  handleChange
} = useField(toRef(props, 'name'), {
  initialValue: props.modelValue,
  // valueProp: props.modelValue
})

const classes = computed(() => {
  return {
    'invalid': meta.validated && !meta.valid,
    'valid': meta.validated && meta.valid
  }
})
</script>

<style scoped>
.input {
  @apply
    block
    w-full
    rounded
    border
    border-slate-300
    py-1.5
    shadow-sm
    text-sm
    placeholder:text-slate-400;
}

.input.invalid {
  @apply border-red-400;
}

.input.valid {
  @apply border-green-600;
}
</style>
```